# Parsing JSON ( again ) in iOS

Tags: iphone, json, ios

I'm just playing with the JSON parser in iOS it's working fine as a ( simple ) example . But I was wonder how one would actually parse something (a bit) more complicated, the a Twitter trends JSON, like this :

```
{
    "trends": {
        "2011-03-13 11:42:17": [
            {
                "events": null,
                "query": "Fukushima",
                "promoted_content": null,
                "name": "Fukushima"
            },
            {
                "events": null,
                "query": "Rebecca Black",
                "promoted_content": null,
                "name": "Rebecca Black"
            },
            {
                "events": null,
                "query": "Pearl Harbour",
                "promoted_content": null,
                "name": "Pearl Harbour"
            },
            ...
            {
                "events": null,
                "query": "Magdalena Neuner",
                "promoted_content": null,
                "name": "Magdalena Neuner"
            }
        ]
    },
    "as_of": 1300016537
}
```

How would one just return the first 3 queries ? in this instance : *Fukushima*, *Rebecca Black* and *Pearl Harbour* .

Using the example code, it goes something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++)
    [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
```

This is for a much simpler feed though, can it be approached the same way for what I'm looking for ?

I'm trying to return the value of "query":

So I`m doing this :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"trends"]);
```

This of course logs the content of the key "trend", how do I go about returning not only the first ( and only ) key of trends but also dig one more level down to return the content of "query" ??

I've also tried something like this :

```
NSString *date = [[[luckyNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"trends"] allKeys] description];
NSArray *trends = [luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"trends"];
NSLog(@"%@", [trends valueForKeyPath:date]);
```

but no go ...

**EDIT (aftet honcheng's answer):**

Because I want to iterate through the results of "trends", I'm doing :

```
NSDictionary *luckyNumbers = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *keys = [[luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"trends"] allKeys];

for (int i =0; i < [keys count]; i++) {

NSLog(@"%@", [keys objectAtIndex:i]);


    }
```

Obviously something is wrong because I'm not getting any result ..

Comment: What JSON parser is this, exactly? The JSON library included in the iOS SDK is private and undocumented, you're not meant to be using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Twitter JSON feed in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289162/parsing-twitter-json-feed-in-ios)

Answer (score 3):

JSON parser usually returns native NSObjects such as NSDictionary and NSArray. After parsing, you just have to treat it like a new object.

[luckyNumbers allKeys] returns an NSArray ["trends", "as_of"]
[[luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"trends"] allKeys"] returns an NSArray ["2011-03-13 11:42:17"]

Since allKeys returns an NSArray, you can just use a for loop to get all your keys.